# How I Do SQL Server Create Table Data type like 1,000.00

Tags: sql-server

I have use the below code but I get an error; I want to save values in my table like 1,000.00 - how correct the code?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_20]
(
    [C1] [DECIMAL](18, 2) FORMAT (,'#,0.00') NULL
)
```

Comment: I would split data strorage, data processing and data presentation into its own functions

Comment: Post the Code here

Comment: SQL Server stores *data*, not *information about how you might want to represent/present the data to humans*. You do formatting during *retrieval*, not *storage*

Comment: SQL Server's numerical datatypes don't have any **formatting** associated with them. Formatting is only relevant in your frontend - you web app, your mobile app - whatever it is. Do any formatting there. In SQL Server, use `INT` (or `BIGINT`) for whole numerical values, or `DECIMAL(p,s)` for fractional values - without any *Format* associated with them....

Comment: so how i can do it i want when i type in my column like 1000 that should be show like 1,000.00

Comment: How i Can use this Query for Graphically when i save my table then this formula will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments are trying to tell you that you don't **store** the number in that format, you convert it to that format while retrieving it:

```
SELECT Format([C1], '#,0.00', 'en-us')
FROM [Table_20]
```

Or even better - in your application which is consuming the data.

Comment: How i Can use this Query for Graphically when i save my table then this formula will work

Comment: "Query for Graphically when i save my table" - What do you mean by this?

Comment: dear when i type in the table  like some amount like 2000 then then auto will show like 2,000.00

Comment: "auto will show" - auto show where? databases don't 'autoshow' anything, you need to query them

Comment: i think you do not understand when i put some data in my table then auto will show the formula its possible ?

Comment: show where? in what program? SQL Server doesn't show you anything, it just stores data, you need another program to look at it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204936/discussion-between-gkan-12-and-milney).

Answer (score 1):

I would split data storage, data processing and data presentation into its own functions

storage:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_20](
    [C1] [decimal](18, 2) NULL
    )
```

insert:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table_20]
Values(1000)
```

presentation:

```
select format([C1], 'n1') from [dbo].[Table_20]
```

> shows - 1,000.0 n1 - for single decimal

more details
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15